# How can I disable a button on a jQuery UI dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

How do I go about disabling a button [on the jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation). I can't seem to find this in any of the documentation in the link above.

I have 2 buttons on the modal confirmation ("Confirm" and "Cancel"). In certain cases, I want to disable the "Confirm" button.

Comment: See the answers in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577548/how-can-i-disable-a-button-in-a-jquery-dialog-from-a-function

Comment: @Erik - The situation has changed a bit since those answers, namely because of the `.button()` plugin, so they're not necessarily the best/cleanest solutions anymore.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

If you're including the [`.button()` plugin/widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/) that jQuery UI contains (if you have the full library and are on 1.8+, you have it), you can use it to disable the button *and* update the state visually, like this:

```
$(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Confirm')").button("disable");
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/rxZPv/1/)...or if you're on an older version or not using the button widget, you can disable it like this:

```
$(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Confirm')").attr("disabled", true)
                                              .addClass("ui-state-disabled");
```

---

If you want it inside a specific dialog, say by ID, then do this:

```
$("#dialogID").next(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Confirm')")
              .attr("disabled", true);
```

In other cases where [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) might give false positives then you can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) like this, but it's overkill here since you know your two buttons.  *If* that is the case in other situations, it'd look like this:

```
$("#dialogID").next(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == "Confirm";
}).attr("disabled", true);
```

This would prevent `:contains()` from matching a substring of something else.

Comment: next() won't work for me, as there is all the "resizable" div between the dialog and the buttonpan. So I used nextAll(), and separate the buttonPan from the button : `$("#dialogID").nextAll(".ui-dialog-buttonpane").find("button:contains('Confirm')").attr("disabled", true).addClass("ui-state-disabled");`

Comment: Note that due to the button pane not being a child of the dialog container you may have issues if your page defines multiple dialogs.

Comment: Excellent solution with `$(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Confirm')").button("disable");` although if you want to disable the button from a function you have for it, you have to _widgetize_ that dialog and disable the button after that; like this `$(this).dialog("widget").find(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Confirm')").button("disable");`

Comment: Note that if you don't want to query the desired button by its text, you can also give a class to the button; jQuery UI's dialog supports an array with objects for the button option, each object containing information about the buttons attributes.

Comment: This worked for me: $(this).closest(".ui-dialog").find("button:contains('Save')").prop("disabled", true).addClass("ui-state-disabled");

Comment: Can I ask how to disable button on load of dialog(on open of dialog) and then enable when one of the radio button inside dialog is selected?

Comment: Probably should use `prop`' rather than `attr`.

Answer (score 220):

Looks like anyone, even in [this linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577548/how-can-i-disable-a-button-in-a-jquery-dialog-from-a-function), have proposed this solution, similar to the first part of the answer given by Nick Craver:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    width: 480,
    height: "auto",
    buttons: [
        {
            id: "button-cancel",
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        {
            id: "button-ok",
            text: "Ok",
            click: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Then, elsewhere, you should be able to use the [API](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Button) for the jquery UI button:

```
$("#button-ok").button("disable");
```

Comment: +1. I am not sure why this answer has not received more votes.  It's the cleanest I have come across and works nicely.

Comment: This needs to be in the docs... it doesn't even show that you can assign an id to buttons.

Comment: This is without a doubt the best answer. There are other solutions out there that do it by searching for the button using selectors that are wrong. Good job Nicola!

Comment: Agree : it's THE solution I was thinking the UI team should implement... :+) You can do even quicker : `{text:"ok",disabled:true,click: function(){}}`

Comment: This is great!  You can also use "class" instead of "id" if you are worried about the id being unique.  Though you will have to type a bit more in order to search for the button: `$("#dialog").dialog("widget").find(".button-ok-class").button("enable")`

Comment: **Hint:** Enabling works similar, see this [linked answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17331742/1016343)

Comment: Does this syntax work with JQ 1.4.2? I just get two buttons labled 0 and 1.

Comment: *Be careful with this solution*: don't forget that ids are to be unique per document. You can do more than assign `id` to a button. You can invoke any jQuery function by passing it as a property of the button object. For example, html: `[ html: '<span class="my-class">Some Text!</span>' ]`. The magic is in line 10529 of the jquery-ui source: `$( "<button></button>", props )` where props is the object that defines your button.

Comment: If you're using a class, then you can also do something like this

jQuery(".selector", jQuery("#dialogID").parent("div")).button("disable");

Replace the #dialogID with "this" (unquoted) if you want to do this from inside a function/event such as create, close etc

Answer (score 51):

You can also use the <s>not</s> now documented `disabled` attribute:

```
$("#element").dialog({
    buttons: [
    {
        text: "Confirm",
        disabled: true,
        id: "my-button-1"
    }, 
    {
        text: "Cancel",
        id: "my-button-2",
        click: function(){            
               $(this).dialog("close");
        }  

    }]
});
```

To enable after dialog has opened, use:

```
$("#my-button-1").attr('disabled', false);
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xvt96e1p/4/

Comment: It's not that it's undocumented. It's that when the buttons are processed, all the properties from the object are executed against their jQuery property equivalent. For example, you can add `attr: { 'data-value' : 'some value here' }` if you wanted to add the attribute `data-value` to the button.

Comment: Not undocumented anymore. It is official.

Comment: This solution is much more elegant than the more popular version. This allows you all the flexibility without the problem of vagely defined selectors.

Comment: Note that the `disabled` attribute must be assigned when creating the buttons.

Comment: Tried to downvote, but I upvoted 4 hours ago and can't do so. This solution does not appear to work properly anymore.

Comment: I just tried it in version 1.11.4 and this answer worked the best for me.  Even if the dialog was already created it still worked.  I used:  disabled: function() { return aaa == bbb; }, and it did the evaluation correctly on the open.

Answer (score 7):

The following works from within the buttons click function:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        height: 'auto', width: 700, modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Add to request list': function(evt) {

                // get DOM element for button
                var buttonDomElement = evt.target;
                // Disable the button
                $(buttonDomElement).attr('disabled', true);

                $('form').submit();
            },
            'Cancel': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: but then you have to click before it is greyed out.

Answer (score 2):

this code disable the button with 'YOUR_BUTTON_LABEL'. you can replace name in contains().
**to disable**

```
$(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('YOUR_BUTTON_LABEL')").button("disable");
```

replace 'YOUR_BUTTON_LABEL' with your button's label.
**to enable**

```
$(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('YOUR_BUTTON_LABEL')").button("enable");
```

Answer (score 1):

A button is identified by the class `ui-button`. To disable a button:

```
$("#myButton").addClass("ui-state-disabled").attr("disabled", true);
```

Unless you are dynamically creating the dialog (which is possible), you will know the position of the button. So, to disable the first button:

```
$("#myButton:eq(0)").addClass("ui-state-disabled").attr("disabled", true);
```

The `ui-state-disabled` class is what gives a button that nice dimmed style.

Answer (score 1):

I created a jQuery function in order to make this task a bit easier. Probably now there is a better solution... either way, here's my 2cents. :)

Just add this to your JS file:

```
$.fn.dialogButtons = function(name, state){
var buttons = $(this).next('div').find('button');
if(!name)return buttons;
return buttons.each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    if(text==name && state=='disabled') {$(this).attr('disabled',true).addClass('ui-state-disabled');return this;}
    if(text==name && state=='enabled') {$(this).attr('disabled',false).removeClass('ui-state-disabled');return this;}
    if(text==name){return this;}
    if(name=='disabled'){$(this).attr('disabled',true).addClass('ui-state-disabled');return buttons;}
    if(name=='enabled'){$(this).attr('disabled',false).removeClass('ui-state-disabled');return buttons;}
});};
```

Disable button 'Ok' on dialog with class 'dialog':

```
$('.dialog').dialogButtons('Ok', 'disabled');
```

Enable all buttons:

```
$('.dialog').dialogButtons('enabled');
```

Enable 'Close' button and change color:

```
$('.dialog').dialogButtons('Close', 'enabled').css('color','red');
```

Text on all buttons red:

```
$('.dialog').dialogButtons().css('color','red');
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function getDialogButton( jqUIdialog, button_names )
{
    if (typeof button_names == 'string')
        button_names = [button_names];
    var buttons = jqUIdialog.parent().find('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button');
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
    {
        var jButton = $( buttons[i] );
        for (var j = 0; j < button_names.length; j++)
            if ( jButton.text() == button_names[j] )
                return jButton;
    }

    return null;
}

function enableDialogButton( jqUIdialog, button_names, enable )
{
    var button = getDialogButton( jqUIdialog, button_names );
    if (button == null)
        alert('button not found: '+button_names);
    else
    {
        if (enable)
            button.removeAttr('disabled').removeClass( 'ui-state-disabled' );
        else
            button.attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass( 'ui-state-disabled' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the buttons array and left only the ones you need.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "buttons", [{
    text: "Close",
    click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
}] );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to disable the first button for example:

```
$('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is
 `Cancel: function(e) {
          $(e.target).attr( "disabled","disabled" );
        }`

This is the shortest and easiest way I found.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using knockout, then this even cleaner. Imagine you have the following:

```js
var dialog = $('#my-dialog').dialog({
    width: '100%',
    buttons: [
        { text: 'Submit', click: $.noop, 'data-bind': 'enable: items() && items().length > 0, click: onSubmitClicked' },
        { text: 'Enable Submit', click: $.noop, 'data-bind': 'click: onEnableSubmitClicked' }
    ]
});

function ViewModel(dialog) {
    var self = this;

    this.items = ko.observableArray([]);

    this.onSubmitClicked = function () {
        dialog.dialog('option', 'title', 'On Submit Clicked!');
    };

    this.onEnableSubmitClicked = function () {
        dialog.dialog('option', 'title', 'Submit Button Enabled!');
        self.items.push('TEST ITEM');
        dialog.text('Submit button is enabled.');
    };
}

var vm = new ViewModel(dialog);
ko.applyBindings(vm, dialog.parent()[0]); //Don't forget to bind to the dialog parent, or the buttons won't get bound.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div id="my-dialog">
  Submit button is disabled at initialization.
</div>
```

The magic comes from the [jQuery UI source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/dialog.js#L489):

```
$( "<button></button>", props )
```

You can basically call ANY jQuery instance function by passing it through the button object.

For example, if you want to use HTML:

```
{ html: '<span class="fa fa-user"></span>User' }
```

Or, if you want to add a class to the button (you can do this multiple ways):

```
{ addClass: 'my-custom-button-class' }
```

Maybe you're nuts, and you want to remove the button from the dom when it's hovered:

```
{ mouseover: function () { $(this).remove(); } }
```

---

I'm really surprised that no one seems to have mentioned this in the countless number of threads like this...

Answer (score 0):

You can disable a button when you construct the dialog:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: [
      { text: "Confirm", click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }, disabled: true },
      { text: "Cancel", click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
    ]
  });
});
```

```css
@import url("https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css");
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="dialog" title="Confirmation">
  <p>Proceed?</p>
</div>
```

Or you can disable it anytime after the dialog is created:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: [
      { text: "Confirm", click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }, "class": "confirm" },
      { text: "Cancel", click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
    ]
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog("widget").find("button.confirm").button("disable");
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
@import url("https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css");
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="dialog" title="Confirmation">
  <p>Button will disable after two seconds.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me --

```
$("#dialog-confirm").html('Do you want to permanently delete this?');
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
    resizable: false,
    title:'Confirm',
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        OK:function(){
            $('#loading').show();
            $.ajax({
                    type:'post',
                    url:'ajax.php',
                    cache:false,
                    data:{action:'do_something'},
                    async:true,
                    success:function(data){
                        var resp = JSON.parse(data);
                        $("#loading").hide();
                        $("#dialog-confirm").html(resp.msg);
                        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
                                resizable: false,
                                title:'Confirm',
                                modal: true,
                                buttons: {
                                    Close: function() {
                                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                    }
                                }
                        });
                    }
                });
        }
    }
});
```