# How to grey out [disable] the jquery button widget

Tags: jquery-ui

i am new to jquery,i need to disable[grey out] the 'Cancel SUP' button which is an jquery BUTTON WIDGET.Below is my code..please some one help me in sorting out this issue

```
var buttons = {
'Exi1': function() {
$(this).dialog('close');
}
};
if(batch.SUPDELIVERYMETHOD === 'Email' && details.STATUS === 'VALID') {
buttons['Re-send SUP'] = resendPass;
}
if(details.STATUS === 'VALID') {
buttons['Cancel SUP'] = function() {
$('#dialog-confirm-cancelsup').dialog('open');
};
}
```

Comment: have you tried `$(button).prop("disabled", true)` type of activity?

Answer (score 0):

Found an older answer here: [How can I disable a button on a jQuery UI dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646408/how-can-i-disable-a-button-on-a-jquery-ui-dialog)

You would use it like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ksk5skxy/

**JavaScript**

```
var btns = {
  "Exi1": function(e) {
    $(this).dialog('close');
  }
};
if (batch.SUPDELIVERYMETHOD === 'Email' && details.STATUS === 'VALID') {
  btns["Re-send SUP"] = resendPass;
}
if (details.STATUS === 'VALID') {
  btns["Cancel SUP"] = function(e) {
    $('#dialog-confirm-cancelsup').dialog('open');
  };
}

$(function() {
  $("#diag").dialog({
    buttons: btns,
    width: "400px"
  });
  $(".ui-dialog-buttonset button:contains('Cancel SUP')").button("disable");
});
```

Comment: @PradeepSubramani am glad to hear this helped. I hope you will mark it as the answer and upvote it if it was useful.