# jQuery-ui dialog - hide buttons using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How do I remove/hide the "Ok" button dynamically using jquery?

```
$('#dialog-save').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: false,
            draggable: true,
            width: 275,
            height: 175,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
```

I was able to change the title using this code -

```
var saveDialog = $('#dialog-save');
saveDialog.dialog('option', 'title', 'Message');
```

Not sure how to remove the buttons. Thanks!

Comment: You can also consider just including an id when you create the button, so that you can access and manipulate it later (see below).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the [`buttons`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-buttons) option in the same way you are setting the title:

```
saveDialog.dialog("option", "buttons", {});
```

Pass in an empty object literal to remove all the buttons. That should be fine, since you appear to only have the one button. If you were to have others, just specify the ones you want to keep when you call the `option` method.

Comment: You beat me to it. I was going to answer the question myself. Works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

One commonly overlooked feature of the UI dialog is that you can set various other properties of the buttons, including 'class' and 'id'. These can be very useful if you need to manipulate the buttons after instantiation.

For example...

```
$('#dialog-save').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: false,
        draggable: true,
        width: 275,
        height: 175,
        {
            id: 'okBtn',
            text: "Ok",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }]
    });

// And then at some other point in the code...
$('#okBtn').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Juste like this won't show the button :

```
$('#dialog-save').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: false,
        draggable: true,
        width: 275,
        height: 175
        }
    });
```

And if you want to remove them after you have shown the dialog 
Maybe something like this;

[How can I disable a button in a jQuery dialog from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577548/how-can-i-disable-a-button-in-a-jquery-dialog-from-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frictionless/JBsY7/)

```
$(function(){
    $('#dialog-save').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            width: 275,
            height: 175,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
    });
    $('#dialog-save').dialog('open');
    $('.change').click(function(){
        $('#dialog-save').dialog("option",{buttons:{}});
        $('#dialog-save').dialog('open');
    });
});​
```