# how to make button disabled using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing MVC application.
I have check box and submit button.

I want to enable submit button on check box's checked event and on unchecked submit button should disable.

How to do this ?

I have below code....

```
    @model PaymentAdviceEntity.Account
    @using PaymentAdviceEntity;


    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
        PaymentAdvice oPA = new PaymentAdvice();
        oPA = (PaymentAdvice)ViewBag.PaymentAdviceObject;

      <div>
             <input type="checkbox" class="optionChk" value="1" /> Paid
        </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Create"  />
    <input type="button"  class="btn-primary" />
    }

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(".optionChk").on("change", function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
        alert("1");

        $(".SubmitButton").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
    } else 
    {
        alert("2");

        $(".SubmitButton").attr("enable", "enable"); 
    }    
});
</script>
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577548/how-can-i-disable-a-button-in-a-jquery-dialog-from-a-function

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set/get the disabled property

```
$(".optionChk").on("change", function () {
     $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled",!this.checked);   
});
```

Also your submit button has no class='Submit' so you need to use the attributes selector.. or give it the class='Submit' and use `$('.Submit')` in place of `$('input[type=submit]')`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/vWCzU/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".optionChk").on("change", function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }    
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3LAxr/3/)

Comment: not working , should I write    $("input[name=submit]").removeAttr("disabled"); as it is ?

Comment: @Nil updated answer (submit was disabled on checkbox checked)

Comment: It wasn't working for you cause you don't have name on your submit, so changed selector to `type=submit`

Comment: sorry, but I am not getting

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.optionChk').click(function(){
        $('input[type="submit"]').toggle('fast');
    });

});
```

and the HTML:

```
<div>
         <input type="checkbox" class="optionChk" value="1" checked="checked" /> Paid
    </div>

<input type="submit" value="Create"  />
```

working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jS72j/2/)

Comment: how to set unchecked in the beginning  ?

Comment: @Nil just remove checked property from the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Disable Submit Button:

```
$(".optionChk").on("change", function () {

if ($(this).is(":checked")) 
{
$("input[type='submit']").attr('disabled',false); //button will be enabled
}
else
{
$("input[type='submit']").attr('disabled',true); //button will be disabled
}
})
```

Code to enable or disable submit button :

```
$("input[type='submit']").attr('disabled',true); //button will be disabled
```