# How to disable a specific button if there is an error message?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, user-interface

[image]

I have here a create account form, beside my **User ID** field the one with the **Sorry, User ID already exists!** is an error message generated by AJAX that notifies the user if the user id he entered obviously exists. **Username** field here also has the same function with **User ID**. my problem is how can I **disable my Create Button** if the error message displayed is **Sorry, User ID/ Username already Exist**? . by the way the message changes into **User ID/ Username available** otherwise.

**Here is my Jquery code**

```
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
     $('#create_btn').hover(function()
     {
       var id = $('#labeler').val();
       var user = $('#labeler2').val();

    if((id.indexOf('available') >= 0) && user.indexOf('available') >= 0)
    {
        $('#create_btn').removeProp('disabled');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#create_btn').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Just disable the button where you _decide_ to show `Sorry, User ID already exists!`

Comment: try return: false; when error is true

Comment: @mshsayem wat jquery function would I use if when I would disable the button? eg. btn_create.hover()?

Comment: `$("#buttonId").prop("disabled",true)`

Comment: @mshsayem I've updated my post, I've added my Jquery code

Comment: I dont see any ajax call here. which function is showing the message: 'Sorry, User ID already exists' ?

Comment: @mshsayem my AJAX is ok, i dont have a problem with it, my concern here is just how to disable the create button based on the text displayed from my notification boxes, that is why I didnt include my AJAX code, the code I posted was just about disabling my create button based on what the notification textboxes contains

Comment: I am not telling that your ajax is not ok. But that function should take care of this kind of task; Just after knowing that user already exists. Then you don't need to check whether 'sorry' is written or not. btw, you can try using `$('#labeler').text()` instead of `$('#labeler').val()`. I suspect `#labeler` is a `span`

Comment: `$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('#create_btn').hover(function()
 {
  var id = $('#labeler').val();
  var user = $('#labeler2').val();
  
  if((id.indexOf('available') >= 0) && user.indexOf('available') >= 0)
  {
   $('#create_btn').removeProp('disabled');
  }
  else
  {
   $('#create_btn').prop('disabled', true);
  }
 });
});` here is my new code, I almost got it , but the problem is when you hover a disabled button It wont get the .hover() of Jquery

Comment: Can you show the ajax calling function which is populating 'sorry' ?

Comment: @mshsayem thank you very much for your help, Ive used the .prop() method you suggested. I've posted my answer below, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this because the code I used above was able to disable the create button but wasn't able to enable it again because .hover() cant read a disabled button. Thank you for all of your help!

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(':text').blur(function()
    {
        var id = $('#labeler').val();
        var user = $('#labeler2').val();

        if((id.indexOf('available') >= 0) && user.indexOf('available') >= 0)
            $('#create_btn').removeProp('disabled');
        else
            $('#create_btn').prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jQuery, you can do this:

```
$("#buttonId").prop("disabled",true)
```

[More discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577548/how-can-i-disable-a-button-in-a-jquery-dialog-from-a-function)

I suspect the `labeler`/`labeler2` are `span`/`div`. In that case you should use `text()`, not `val()`. Change those lines into:

```
var id = $('#labeler').text();//user id notification AJAX
var user = $('#labeler2').text();//username notification AJAX
```